# How many elements are in $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}\;$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just wanted to know how many elements are in this list. I know there are not zero but the many lists of empty sets, kind of confuse me. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image: List of empty sets]

Comment: This is the von Neumann construction for the number $3$, and such it has $3$ elements.

Comment: Each of the pink shapes encircles one element, for a total of 3 elements.

Comment: The usual trick: replace $\varnothing$ by $x$, then replace $\{x\}$ by $y$. Clearly, $x\neq y$, since $y=\{x\}$; whereas $x\notin x$. Finally, we have $z=\{x,y\}$, and clearly $z\neq x$ and $z\neq y$. So you have a set, $\{x,y,z\}$, all three are distinct elements. How many elements does your set have?

Answer (score 3):

Think upon $\varnothing = \{\}$ as an "empty bag".

Now think upon your set: $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\}$ itself as being a "bag".

(EDIT: It probably needs to be pointed out that if we want to use this analogy, a "set" is a "bag in which everything in it is different".)

You look inside your bag, and you see three things:

- One of them is an empty bag.
- One of them is a bag which itself contains an empty bag.
- One of them is a bag which contains two things: an empty bag, and a bag containing an empty bag.

(And as an "empty bag" is not the same thing as a "bag with an empty bag in it", and so on, everything in your bag is different from everything else in it.)

You are being asked to find out how many things your (top level) bag contains. But you are *not* being asked to take all those bags out and count all the things inside those inner bags.

You just need to peek inside and see, "Oh yes, three bags, who cares what's in those bags?"

Does this make it clearer what you are being asked to do?

Oh by the way, call them "sets" not "lists". Because reasons.

Comment: What is it about this post which makes it not useful?

Comment: This is a bad analogy. My bag contains three empty bags, "oh yes, three bags, who cares what's in those bags?"

Comment: @MatthewTowers Yes but your "bag" is not a set. A defining concept of a set is that everything in it is different.

Comment: @MatthewTowers I've edited my post to reflect what you said.